# readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING Error?

Tags: string, spring-boot, document, bson

> My code is like below, what should I do to avoid this error?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/deneme", consumes = "application/json")
public void logout(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> userId) {
    tokensService.logout(userId.get("userId").toString());
}
public void logout(String userId){
    try {
        tokensRepository.logout(userId,"");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }`public interface TokensRepository extends MongoRepository<Tokens, String> {

@Query("Update tokens t set t.token=:token where t._id=:userId")
void logout(@Param("userId") String userId, @Param("token") String token);
```

}`

Comment: did you tried mongoTemplate for update operation ?

Comment: yes,I tried but got same error.

Comment: Did you find a fix yet? I running into the same issue.

Comment: @Query doesn't work here. I used Update update = new Update();  update.set() method and mongoTemplate updateFirst method.